# Видео фоном на сайте

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

как сделать видео фоном как на этом сайте? http://comfort.moskow-city.ru/video/ (нужно подождать 15 сек)
спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно там (через яваскрипт, видимо) выдается HTML5 тег [video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) (старым браузерам, скорее всего, выдается флеш плеер), который засунут в абсолютно позиционированный контейнер (это достигается css-свойствами position:absolute, и, иногда, z-index), что позволяет имитировать им задний фон.

Чувствую необходимость предупредить, что пользователям это скорее не понравится, чем понравится.

Comment: понравится / не понравится это покажут АБ тесты :)

Comment: если видео будет без звука, или будет изначально без звука + будет кнопка включить/выключить звук, то это неплохой вариант, если видео со звуком - однозначно нет, плохой вариант.

Comment: Да на примере этого же сайта - висит на заднем плане, отвлекает, цель его неясна, сверху уродливо примостилась надпись, само видео заметно триозит загрузку страницы.